# tree.nodes(root).reverse(); returns too many nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a D3 tree layout and I want to remove a single node from a parent. I have that working. I basically go into the data structure, grab the parent node's children array and remove the node I want to delete. Then I call "update" which is pretty much the generic update that anyone calls in these examples.

```
var update = function () {
    //At this point the node I removed isn't in the parent's child node array.
    //I only remove leaf nodes. I verified that the node isn't in the root variable.
    nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();
    //The nodes array is returned with extra, duplicate nodes. 
    //They seem to repeat based on what node is deleted.
    links = tree.links(nodes); 
    //Links appear all over the place because of the redundant nodes.
...
```

My delete function looks like this:

```
 //*Only nodes without children can be deleted.
    this.removeNode = function (node) {
        parent = node.parent;
        parent.children.forEach(function(child, i) { 
            if(node.name === child.name) 
            {
                parent.children.splice(i,1); //remove the node from its parent
            }
            if(parent.children.length === 0)
            {
            parent.end = true;
            }
        });
   update();
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: If you don't also make sure to delete any associated links then I doubt d3 will do that for you. Also, to be on the safe side, check if using concat to duplicate the array `nodes = tree.nodes(root).concat().reverse()` — rather than mutating the layout's copy of that array — makes a difference.

Comment: D3 will remove the links when they're recalculated via "links = tree.links(nodes);" and then drawn. I have seen that happen. Since the nodes are used to create the links, the extra nodes throw everything off. I don't call a concat anywhere in my code. I've even set my nodes array to empty and the extra nodes still show up. I'm thinking that the nodes are somehow lingering inside of the tree object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was adding child nodes after the fact. I'm using D3 to make a multiparent tree. I realize I could use a network map for that, but I found the force layout to be erratic and difficult to tame. The issue was a parent node would point to another parent's child. This caused unexpected behavior. To make a multiparent tree you have to manage the extra link connections outside of the tree layout.

http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/6afc2ecb05b191359862